# sql query to have the prescription information the medication_info is resulting

Tags: mariadb

I have this SQL query to get the prescription information. The `medication_info` looks like this:

```
XAVEL 1%(10MG/ML : 5
XAVEL 1%(10MG/ML : 1
```

What I wish to have is:

```
XAVEL 1%(10MG/ML : 6
```

This is what I have:

```
SELECT
  o.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(REPLACE(lp.name, '(', ''), ' ', REPLACE(lp.dosage, ')', ''), ' : ', c.amount) SEPARATOR '\n') AS medication_info,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(REPLACE(nlp.name, '(', ''), ' ', REPLACE(nlp.dosage, ')', ''), ' : ', nc.amount) SEPARATOR '\n') AS non_completed_info,
  CONCAT(cl.fname, ' ', cl.name) AS client_name,
  cl.id AS client_id,
  u.name AS user_name,
  u.id AS user_id,
  o.id_pharm,
  DATE_FORMAT(o.created, '%d/%m/%Y') AS order_created,
  DATE_FORMAT(o.ord_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS ord_date,
  DATE_FORMAT(o.next_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS next_date,
  o.dure,
  o.ModifiedDate,
  o.complited
FROM `prescription` o
LEFT JOIN `changement` c ON o.id = c.id_ord
LEFT JOIN `inventory` p ON c.id_prodoit = p.id
LEFT JOIN `list_prodoit` lp ON p.list_prodoit = lp.id
LEFT JOIN `noncompliant` nc ON o.id = nc.ord_id
LEFT JOIN `list_prodoit` nlp ON nc.list_prodoit = nlp.id
LEFT JOIN `client` cl ON o.id_client = cl.id
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON o.id_user = u.`your text`id
WHERE o.id_pharm = $pharm_id
GROUP BY o.id
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! A [mcve] is a great start.

Comment: Am i understanding that you are wanting to *add* the end value of multiple "XAVEL 1%(10MG/ML" records together?  i.e  if you have 3 records, "1", "2" and "3" that you want 6 as the outcome?

Comment: Add the following information to the question: 1) the `CREATE TABLE` statements 2) some `INSERT` statements with sample data 3) the desired result, with a description of the algorithm.

Comment: yes this is right

Comment: the sciptr to creat is too long i will try to make it simple